# Using Images in Azure Blob Storage as input

Tags: python, azure, keras, stream, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a project where I use a keras model I built to classify the images stored in a Azure Blob Storage and export the result as a .csv file. I was able to do this by utilizing get_blob_to_path and downloading some images to my laptop. However, as there are too many pictures, I want to do this without downloading the pictures either through get_blob_to_bytes or get_blob_to_stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a simpler solution to load images from Azure Blob Storage without downloading first is to generate the blob url with sas token to pass to `imageio.imread`.

Here is my code changed from yours.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import imageio
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform
import pandas as pd

account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'

# generate the container-level sas token 

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
token = block_blob_service.generate_container_shared_access_signature(container_name, permission=ContainerPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1),)

# generate the list of blob urls with sas token

blob_names = service.list_blob_names(container_name)
df = pd.read_csv("~/Desktop/list.csv")
blob_urls_with_token = (f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}?{token}" for blob_name in blob_names if blob_name in df.values)

#function to prepare the image for keras model

def load(img_sas_url):
    image = imageio.imread(img_sas_url)  # directly read image from the blob url with sas token
    image = np.array(image).astype('float32')/255
    image = transform.resize(image, (224, 224, 3))
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    return image

#predicting the images and append it to a datafram

predictions = []
images=[]
name = []
probs =[]
for img_sas_url in blob_urls_with_token:
    image = load(img_sas_url)
    prediction = model.predict_classes(image)
    prob = model.predict(image).max()
    predictions.append(prediction)
    probs.append(prob)
    images.append(file)
    name.append(root.split('\\')[4])

output = pd.DataFrame(
{'ImageID':name,
 'ImageName':images,
 'Predictions':predictions,
 'Probabilities':probs
})
```

Hope it helps.